# how to link many transactions to one transaction in SAP

Tags: abap

I have created three reports with related three transactions but I need now to join all these transactions into one transaction code.

How can I achieve that and What steps should I follow ?

Comment: The term "join all these transactions" may correspond to several different things. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I mean in one screen I can switch between tcodes without leaving the current screen each time. 
One screen I find :
Tcode A
Tcode B
Tcode C...

Comment: The standard UX is to have these Transaction Code links defined in the top menu of the initial screen of each TCode. Isn't it what you want to do? (when the option is selected, the ABAP code uses `LEAVE TO TRANSACTION` or `CALL TRANSACTION` to go there).

Comment: yeah @SandraRossi that seems to be what I want. can you tell what to add exactely in each code ? Or a small example

Comment: you can use [this sample](http://sapabaperguide.blogspot.com/2017/02/interactive-reports-with-ucomm.html) as a starting point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a routing report with pushbuttons and process user-command on button click.

```
REPORT ZTEST1.

SELECTION-SCREEN PUSHBUTTON 3(10) TCODE1
  USER-COMMAND TCODE1.
SELECTION-SCREEN SKIP 1.
SELECTION-SCREEN PUSHBUTTON 3(10) TCODE2
  USER-COMMAND TCODE2.

INITIALIZATION.
  TCODE1 = 'SU01D'.
  TCODE2 = 'SU53'.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN.
  CASE SY-UCOMM.
    WHEN 'TCODE1'.
      CALL TRANSACTION 'SU01D'.
    WHEN 'TCODE2'.
      CALL TRANSACTION 'SU53'.
  ENDCASE.
```